# Why am I not able to do a jQuery POST return to another domain?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

When I use json in my $.ajax all I get is a red 200 in firebug and data is inserted in database, however I am not getting the JSON return.

When I use jsonp, I am not even able to submit the page.

Here is my code:

```
<html> 
    <head> 
    <title>Register</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b1/jquery.mobile-1.0b1.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jquery.mobile.datebox.min.css" /> 




    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b1/jquery.mobile-1.0b1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jquery.mobile.datebox.min.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

                     $("#contactus").submit(function(event) {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://apsessionmobile.mobi/index.php/api/apsessionmobile/user/",
                    data: $("#contactus").serialize(),
                    dataType: 'jsonp',

                    success: function(msg){
                     //   jQuery("#status").html(msg);
                    alert(msg);
                    }
        })
    })
});
</script>

</head> 
<body> 



<div data-role="page" data-theme="e">

    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Register</h1>
        <a href="home.html" data-icon="back" class="ui-btn-left" data-rel="back">Back</a>
        <a href="home.html" data-icon="home" class="ui-btn-right">Home</a>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   

    <div align="center">

    <form action="JavaScript:void(0);" name="contactus" id="contactus">


    <div id="fnameDiv" data-role="fieldcontain">


        <label for="username">Create User Name:</label>     
        <input id="username" name="username" type="text" />


        <label for="email">Email:</label>       
        <input id="email" name="email" type="text" />



        <label for="password">Password:</label>     
        <input id="password" name="password" type="password" />



        <label for="password2">Repeat Password:</label>     
        <input id="password2" name="password2" type="password" />




        <button type="submit">Register</button>



    </div>




    </form>

    </div>

    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer" data-id="thefooter" data-position="fixed">
        <h4></h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
```

Comment: no response at all? what does the firebug say? can you post relevant server side code that is sending the json response...

Answer (score 0):

cross domain requests are not allowed through ajax. however, try to use network inspector to see if:
1) request is made when you submit form
2) what is sent
3) what content is returned (if any)

if there are cross domain access issues, or any other js error, console should tell you that.

Comment: The post is made and database is populated. The form fields are sent successfully. I am just not getting any return.

Comment: Nothing happens when I do jsonp

Comment: network inspector, pick request and select "content" to see what was returned by server. if nothing, you should look at your backend which is performing db update. perhaps you have premature "exit" for some reason. if you have php backend, review error_log. if you have error after db population and if error display is off, you would get empty page

Answer (score 0):

1. JSONP only works for GET requests, because JSONP simply includes a
   `script` element in the HTML that loads the page, which contains the
   JSON with padding (a callback) that handles said JSON data. And then removes the `script`                element again.
2. I'm not familiar enough with jQuery, so this is going to be a wild guess. But what's probably happening is a hidden form is submitted to a hidden iframe, with the external request. This works partially, as the data is sent succesfully, except because the hidden iframe now is used by another domain JavaScript is unable to read the content and thus is unable to parse the JSON response inside.

Comment: without adding your own iframe transport, jquery doesn't automatically create a hidden form/iframe. It just cannot process the return data because it isn't from the same domain.

Comment: Hm interesting, I always thought the data wouldn't even be sent to a different domain with a XMLHttpRequest. Ah well!